# variable reset to default in realm

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper

In RealmSwift, I have an Object, Message.

I am using ObjectMapper to map its properties from a REST service. I also want a local property, `dynamic var read:Bool = false` to keep track if a user has read a message.

```
try! realm.write({
    m.read = true
})
```

I can see the value updated in Realm Browser.

However every time I fetch the objects from the service, the variable is reset to its default value. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure if it is a RealmSwift or ObjectMapper thing.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis as to why this is happening is because when you fetch the objects from the server, you receive JSON which you then map into new `Message` objects (distinct from the previous `Message` objects, where you had set `read = true`). These message objects are initialized with `read = false`, and when they are persisted in the Realm the `false` value overwrites the previously stored `true` value.

(As far as I can tell, ObjectMapper does not allow you to take an existing model object and 'update' or 're-populate' its values with a new JSON value.)

There are a few things you can try. You can try retrieving the values of `read` for all the `Message`s you created from your JSON response, and updating the values of `read` on the new `Message` objects before you save them to the Realm. Another option is to store this information out-of-band: create a new object class containing just user-side info (e.g. a message ID and the `read` flag), and store those in the Realm alongside your `Message` objects.

Comment: I've solved using the RealmOptional<Bool> type. However I'm still interested on why this doesn't work. I suppose you could be right.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: declare the variable like this:

```
@objc dynamic var name : String = ""
```

I'm using AlamofireObjectMapper (5.0.0) Realm (3.0.2) RealmSwift (3.0.2) and iOS 11

```
class Category: Object, Mappable {
(...) 
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
(...)
}
```

some view controller:

```
lazy var categories: Results<Category> = { self.realm.objects(Category.self) }()
```

without dynamic categories prints everything but `categories[indexPath.row].name` prints ""

when I added dynamic to the variable declaration everything worked fine.